# Matlab efficient code generation

Tags: c, matlab, matlab-deployment

I am generating C code from Matlab coder.
I have a function as follows

```
function C = foo( A, B ) %#codegen
    for j=1:100,
    C = C+A(j);
    end
end
```

The code for this function in c generated is

```
void foo(float A[100],B,float* C){
    for(j=0;j<100;j++){
    *C+=A[j];
    }
}
```

I want the code to be efficient and generated in the following way:

```
void foo(float* A,B,float* C){
//here B is the length of the array
for(j=0;j<B;j++){
    *C+=*(A+j);
}
}
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: I believe your MATLAB code will return error since C variable is not defined.

Comment: How do you generate the C code from the Matlab?

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand the whole story, but why don't you change your matlab code to actually use `B` for a start and tell us what happens then, like

```
function C = foo( A, B ) %#codegen
    for j=1:B,
        C = C+A(j);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Matlab Coder expects vectorized code:

Try again on this one:

```
function C = foo( A, B ) %#codegen
    C = sum(A(1:100));
end
```

Comment: In the OP's example, `C` is scalar... it seems he wants `C=sum(A(1:B));`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to optimize your Matlab code to be more like what you want in C.  The Matlab code is accessing 100 elements in A; which is what the generated C is replicating.  If you want it to only go to `B` then you would have to make that in Matlab.

```
% MATLAB
function C = foo( A, B ) %#codegen
  for j=1:B,
  C = C+A(j);
  end
end
```